# How to create property for BOOL Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Code:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) BOOL val;
```

Error:

> Property with ‘retain(or Strong)’ attribute must be of object type

I want to use this bool object in another class. I am creating it in .h file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOOL is a primitive type (thus not a pointer, so no memory management).

You declare the property this way :

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL val;
```

(you can also explicitly write **assign** instead of strong/retain)

Comment: Note that this is true for all primitive types: properties for integers, floats, structs and many more need to be declared in this way.

Comment: Thanks it solved..

Comment: Your last sentence in the answer makes no sense. It *has* to be `assign`. In fact, `assign` is the default for non-object properties.

Comment: You are right, my sentence was not clear, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `assign` attribute, which is the default for `BOOL` anyway:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL val;
```